# How find this sum of $\sum_{d\mid n}\dfrac{G(d)}{d}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

Find
$$\sum_{d\mid n}\dfrac{G(d)}{d}$$

where $G(d)$ define the  $d$   largest odd divisor, for example
$G(1)=1,\, G(2)=1,\, G(3)=3,\, G(4)=1,\, G(5)=5,\, G(6)=3$,

$G(7)=7,G(8)=1,G(9)=9,G(10)=5$
and so on

It's easy find 
$G(k)=\begin{cases}
k&k=2n-1,\\
G(k/2)&k=2n.
\end{cases}$

Thank you.

Comment: How is $\,G(2)=G(4)=G(8)=1\,$ **and not** $\,2\,$ ? Not to mention that $\,1\,$ is *not* a prime. BTW, also $\,9\,$ is not a prime.//

Comment: I think he means that $G(d)$ is the largest odd divisor, which would make this question somewhat familiar.

Comment: That sounds sound, @Calvin...but the OP didn't take the time to address my question. -1

Comment: yes,I meaning $G(d)$ is the largest odd divisor,Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\rm n=ab$ with $\rm a,b$ coprime, then every divisor $\rm d\mid ab$ has a unique refinement $\rm d=d_1d_2$ satisfying $\rm d_1\mid a$ and $\rm d_2\mid b$. In particular, if $\rm n=2^rm$ with $\rm m$ odd, then every positive divisor $\rm d\mid n$ is uniquely of the form $\rm 2^k v$ with $\rm 0\le k\le r$ and $\rm v\mid m$. Thus

$$\rm \sum_{d\mid n}\frac{G(d)}{d}=\sum_{k=0}^r\sum_{v\mid m}\frac{G(2^km)}{2^km}=\sum_{k=0}^r\frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{v\mid m}1=\left(2-\frac{1}{2^{r}}\right)\sigma_0(m)$$

which can be expressed with standard number-theoretic devices as

$$\rm \sum_{d\mid n}\frac{G(d)}{d}=\left(2-|n|_2\right)\sigma_0\left(|n|_2n\right). $$

(see [$\rm p$-adic absolute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order#p-adic_Norm) and [divisor sigma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)).

Comment: oh,Thank you,It's very nice,But I have some question,if we look for this $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{G(k)}{k}$?,I find if $n=2^m$,then $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{G(k)}{k}=\dfrac{1}{2^m}+\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\dfrac{2^{m-i-1}}{2^i}=\dfrac{2^{2m+1}+1}{3\cdot 2^m}$,but for $n=2^m\cdot r$,then $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{G(k)}{k}=?$

Comment: @math110 I get $$\rm \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{G(k)}{k}=\sum_{r\ge0}\frac{1}{2^r}\#\{1\le k\le n: |k|_2=2^{-r}\}$$ 
 $$\rm = \sum_{r\ge0} \frac{1}{2^r} \left( \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^r} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^{r+1}} \right\rfloor \right) = \lfloor n\rfloor - \frac{1}{2} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor - \frac{1}{4} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{4} \right\rfloor - \cdots $$ which I don't at the moment see an obvious way to simplify any further.